# I don't understand why my laravel saids my codes of validation is wrong

Tags: php, laravel

## Basic Information

I'm developing a simple Web application using Laravel6.0.

## Error Message

`syntax error, unexpected '$this'(T_VARIABLE)`

## My Codes

`app/Http/Controllers/ProfileController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\stories;
use App\History;
use App\Posts;
use App\Profile;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Storage;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request) 
    {

      $plus = Posts::all();

      return view('stories.index2', compact('plus'));
    }

    public function upload(Request $request)
      {
        $this->validate($request, [
          'file' => [
            
            'required',
            
            'file',
            
            'image',
            
            'mimes:jpeg,png',
          ]
        ]);
  
        if ($request->file('file')->isValid([])) {
          $path = $request->file->store('public');
          return view('stories.index2')->with(compact('filename','plus'));
        } else {
          return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors();
        }
    }
    
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $d = new \DateTime();
      $d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
      $dir = $d->format('Y/m');
      $path = sprintf('public/posts/%s', $dir);

      
      $data = $request->except('_token');

      foreach ($data['plus'] as $k => $v) {

        $filename = '';

        
        $posts = Posts::take(1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
          
          $filename = $post->id + 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
        }
        unset($post);

        
        if ($filename == false) {
          $filename = 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
        }

        
        $v->storeAs($path, $filename);

        $post_data = [
          'path' => sprintf('posts/%s/', $dir),
          'name' => $filename
        ];
        $a = new Posts();
        $a->fill($post_data)->save();
      }

      unset($k, $v);

      return redirect('/');
    }

    
   public function create(Request $request)
  {
      $this -> validate($request, Profile::$rules);
      
      $profile = new Profile;
      $form = $request->all();
​
      if (isset($form['image'])) {
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/image');
        $profile->image_path = basename($path);
      } else {
          $profile->image_path = null;
      }
​
      unset($form['_token']);
     
      unset($form['image']);
​
      $profile->fill($form);
      $profile->save();

      return redirect('/');
  }

    public function add()
      {
        return view('profile.create2');
      }
      
    public function edit()
      {
        return view('profile.edit');
      }
      

}
```

`app/Profile.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
     public static $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    );
}
```

## What I tried.

I tried this code,

```
~
$request -> validate(Profile::$rules);
~
```

also, this code

```
~
$request -> validate([Profile::$rules]);
~
```

and this one,

```
~
$request -> validate([
 'title' => 'required',
 'body' => 'required',
]);
~
```

When I developed an application using Laravel 5.8.35, there were nothing wrong with this code.
Is it cause of the laravel version?
or is it simply wrong my codes?
please help me.

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong with the code. But may I ask why you're adding space before and after  `->`?

Comment: Can you please identify the line that throws the error? Please ad `use App\Profile;` to your ProfileController

Comment: The reason of why  I added the space between `->` is just looks simple. I couldn't find the error too.

Comment: I add `use App\Profile;` at  the top of the file.  and my problem code is in the `public function create()`

Comment: You've got some sort of special character in your `create` function. Remove the whole thing and retype it from scratch, without copy/pasting.

Comment: I retyped the code then my error massage has been disappeared. Thank you for the comments.